# What type of moulding is this?

Tags: trim

My 100 year old house in Wisconsin, US has this type of trim around all windows and doors (see picture below). I am adding a door to close off a section of the house and would like to purchase the same type of millwork. It's a simple enough profile that I could probably just make it if I needed to, but buying it pre-made will save a lot of time. The problem is I don't know what it's called in order to search for it or ask for it!

Some dimensions:

- Top 4" wide x 9/16" thick
- Sides 4 1/4" wide x 3/4" thick
- Plinth block 4 1/4" wide by 1" thick by 9" high

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an off the shelf 1X material. If the long pieces on the sides are 3/4" or perhaps 11/16" thick, the width may be 3 1/2 or 4 1/2" wide? The top piece looks like the same width, maybe 1/2" thick. The "blocks" at the bottom are perhaps 1" thick or near that. All these sizes are standard lumber sizes.

Since the trim has no shaped profile that I can see, the only thing that may need to be done is using a table saw to reduce the width of the material if the original width may be 4 1/4 " instead of 4 1/2"

Since your house is an older home with thicker walls as a rule, and you have a modern day door in place, the door, made for thinner modern walls needs what is called "jamb extensions". This is what is noticeable on the trim between the door jamb and the trim itself. The jamb extension adds extra width to the door jamb to allow the trim to fit properly. Otherwise there would be a sizeable gap where the trim meets the door jamb.

If my guesses in sizes are correct you will need 1/2" by 5" (4 1/2"net) for the top. 1 by 5" for the sides (3/4" or 11/16" X 4 1/2" net) and 5/4X 5 or 6 ripped to be slightly wider that the trim on the sides, unless the sides are 4 1/4" wide then the blocks can be 4 1/2" wide. All this material is available in finger joint primed wood or MDF (Medium Density Fiberboard)

Comment: What I'm having trouble finding is the board for the top -- actual dimensions are 4" by 9/16". I can find some hobby boards but these are only 3' long, but I'm trimming out a double door so need at least 5'.

Comment: Find someone with a planer and you can mill your own pretty quick.

Comment: there is baseboard that is 9/16" thick in FJP and MDF that is wide enough to rip the top profile off to get you what you need.    Look for WM618

Comment: @Jack good idea -- hadn't even thought of that.